# when I launch my application then it crash

Tags: android

when I launch my application then it crash and in log screen error show is "User cannot be cast to java.util.List"

```
    package com.example.harryproject;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView mylist;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mylist=findViewById(R.id.list);
        User user=new User();
        user.setF_name("ali");
        user.setF_pic(R.drawable.ora);
        List<User> arr=new<User>ArrayList();
        arr.add(user);
        HarryAdapter ad=new HarryAdapter(this, (List<User>) user);// error here
        mylist.setAdapter(ad);
      }
   }
   //in logcat screen show this message "com.example.harryproject.User cannot be cast to 
   //java.util.List"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will fix your problem:

```
HarryAdapter ad=new HarryAdapter(this, arr);
```

If you are using `List<User> user`, it may be null because user it is not an instance of the list but it's an instance of `User`.